# How do I add fees to token Contract?

Tags: solidity

Thanks for your help. My question is that I got a ERC20 token Contract which can allow me to create a erc20 token. I want to create a dapp which allows somebody else to create their own token. In this case how do I to add extra fees in my Contract? I mean people who deploy this contract, they would need to pay the gas fee and pay extra fees which send to my wallet address.

Answer (score 1):

To add fees to a token contract you can modify its `transfer` and `transferFrom` functions. Those functions are used when tokens are transferred directly or indirectly.

You can for example calculate 1% of each token transfer, reduce it from the amount to be transferred and send the 1% to some predefined address.

You can't take fees in Ethers from token transfers, since the functions would not be usable by typical clients anymore.

Comment: Can I add your Telegram? I'm new to solidity. I hope that you can help me step by step i can pay for your helping thanks bro

Comment: My Telegram is open