# Hello I want to be done

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, contract-design, contract-invocation

there is a question when adding gas fee to my cryptocurrency, I want to distribute coin gas fee to holders of nft (my project), how is it possible in solidity, can you help me, thank you
My naime jeff

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear the issue. What do you mean with 'distribute coin gas'? Is the 'coin gas' a token? Does the nft project run in Ethereum or another chain?

Comment: Hello my brother, can you add the gas to me token and then it will be distributed to nft holders I have an nft project

Comment: Sorry, but I don't speak Arabic.

Comment: I want to ask you, please, if you allow, can you add a gas fee to a token? Yes or No

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. Gas measures how much work a transaction requires. Gas doesn't exists as a separate token. If it is a ERC20 token you could charge a fee in every transfer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/101526/how-do-i-add-fees-to-token-contract.